# How to execute useEffect hook callback only when a single value from the hook callback changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state, usecallback

It is being mentioned in the [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) that every thing that is supposed to be changed needs to be present in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook.

I could make use of `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` but this is not the ideal way to do it I think.

But what would you do if you want to trigger a Side Effect only when a certain state changes? Not the other things being used to it?

I have a workaround but that doesn't works if you have multiple side effects listening to unique states.

```
const [state1, setState1] = useState(1);
const [state2, setState2] = useState(2);

const fetchDataWithState = useCallback(() => {
  action.fetchData({
    state1,
    state2,
  })
}, [state1, state2])

// Effect to listen to the changes of state1
useEffect(() => {
  // Some random work related to state1
  fetchDataWithState()
}), [fetchDataWithState, state1])

// Effect to listen to the changes of state2
useEffect(() => {
  // Some random work related to state2
  fetchDataWithState()
}), [fetchDataWithState, state2])
```

The above code doesn't work if there are multiple side effects, each specific for a particular state.

If `state1` gets changed, the `fetchDataWithState` will have a different reference, so it will lead to execute the callback in the second `useEffect` which was supposed to triggered only when the `state2` changes.

Or should I use `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` by not passing `fetchDataWithState` it in the dependency array.

Comment: Your current code is equivalent to `useEffect(() => { fetchDataWithState(); fetchDataWithState(); }, [fetchDataWithState]);` Yes, you should listen to the warning.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts rephrased the question. How do I execute the `useEffect` callback only when a single state in it changes?

`useEffect(() => {
  action.fetchData({ state1, state2 })
}, [state1])
`

Answer (score 2):

Store the previous value of `state1` in a `ref`, and only invoke the function if `state1` actually changes:

```js
const [state1, setState1] = useState(1);
const [state2, setState2] = useState(2);
const state1PreviousRef = useRef(0); // Any initial value that's the same type as state1, but not the same value

// only invoke action.fetchData if state1 changes:
useEffect(() => {
  // state1 changed from last time
  if (state1 !== state1PreviousRef.current) {
    action.fetchData({state1, state2});
  }

  // update previous to current
  state1PreviousRef.current = state1;
}, [
  state1,
  state2,
  action, // might or might not be necessary, depending on where this is defined (you don't show this in your example)
  state1PreviousRef, // not necessary, but **actually** exhaustive
]);
```

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Good call. I didn't write this in an editor: thanks for catching that.

Comment: This would work but I don't think it's the ideal way since there could be "N" number of states and I would have to have a separate ref for each one of them? And the check too.

Comment: (1/2) If they need to acted on together, then why are they separate states?

Comment: (2/2) Nothing is preventing you from storing _n_ items in an array or object in a single ref and working with that single collection.

Comment: There are multiple states as each state has its own use case but when an API request is being made then both of them needs to be added in the requestObject. 

Anyway, I think you are right on this one I could have the previous state stored in a ref and then act accordingly. However, do you have any other suggestion to handle such a case like I mentioned in this comment?

Comment: No, not unless you missed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70503939/how-to-execute-useeffect-hook-callback-only-when-a-single-value-from-the-hook-ca/70504112?noredirect=1#comment124630547_70504112).